# Invalid function: No module named 'psycopg2'

Tags: digital-ocean

I created an account on the Digital Ocean platform and hired the Functions and Databases services. Now I'm trying to run a Python script, but I get the error "Invalid function: No module named 'psycopg2'".

Googling, I found that I would have to create a requirements.txt file and run a bash script, but I didn't understand where that would be.